# How did Castiel break into Lucifer's cage? Why was Raphael unable to?

Tags: supernatural

We know it was Castiel who broke into Lucifer's cage to release Sam's body, but has it ever been explained how he done this? I was thinking that he used the Rings of the Horsemen, but didn't Death get his one back?
 Remember how Raphael intended to do the same, but to release Michael and Lucifer instead? He was an Archangel, obviously far more powerful and knowledgeable than Castiel, and yet he seemed unable to do this?

Moving on, even after breaking into Lucifer's cage, I don't see how Castiel could simply walk in and grab Sam's body, when two of the most powerful beings were in there too (not the two most powerful, but definitely in the top 5 beings we've seen in the show). Surely Michael and Lucifer could have escaped once it was open, as there's no way Castiel could evade an Archangel or subdue one (let alone two). The only other other being to have performed such a feat was Death, but him being able to do it is understandable.

Comment: Robert Picardo's character (the Leprechaun) implied that there were other ways into the cage. Castiel may have used those, or he may have bargained with the Fairies directly. I don't remember this ever being explained, though

Comment: I think it was not about power or knowledge. The point to notice is that the cage was in hell and boo ya, Crowley was the king of hell!

Comment: @Dvij I don't think so. If he wanted to, Raphael could simply walk into hell, and I doubt even a million demons could do any harm.

Answer (score 2):

Castiel never explains how he got Sam out, so we have no idea how he pulled it off. In fact, he barely says anything at all about it, even having Crowley take credit for it to hide his involvement. After Season 6 ended, the cage has been largely forgotten except for a very rare offhand remark about it (including the fact that *Adam* body and soul are still trapped in there with Michael and Lucifer.)

---

Other than the fact that the Horsemen's rings open it, we only find out a few tidbits about getting into and out of the cage:

- The leprechauns *claim* they can get in and out, though we never see it.
- Death can move in and out freely.

However, there's one very likely explanation for how Castiel pulled Sam out without freeing Michael or Lucifer: he only extracted Sam's *body*, not his soul.

It was a key plot point during that Season that "something was wrong" with Sam, and that turned out to be the problem. The reason this is significant is because archangels don't possess bodies -- they're "all soul" -- so it's likely that whatever Castiel did to get Sam out was only capable of extracting the physical part.

(Why he didn't also extract Adam the same way is a much bigger problem.)

Comment: +1 I agree completely. The simple fact is the cage has never been properly explained on  the show, including how to get in and out of it (And, let's be honest, I doubt the writers have given it much thought). Based on the events in the show, though, it appears that a powerful enough entity  (i.e. Death) is able to by pass the cage entirely, and that a physical thing is a lot easier to get out of the cage than a soul (making it possible for entities like cas to be strong enough to get a body out but not a soul)

Answer (score 0):

I think Crowley lent Cas some souls from Hell, but it seemed it was only enough for one body.
Either that or just as Cas came back to life (after Lucy exploded him) he probably grabbed Sam by the shoe string, grabbing the body but just missing the soul. And maybe the reason he didn't grab Adam is because of the risk of one of the Archangels catching him in the act. Cas had to have been as sneaky as possible.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Do you have any evidence to support your speculation?  This will go a long way to improving your answer's quality!

Answer (score -2):

I, actually, agree with you on this.  It seems like one of those things that happens but the show doesn't feel it necessary to get into detail about (at least, not at the moment.)  Which does leave it open to come up in the future in some story line that the writers don't even know they want to write yet...

Anyhoo, I always thought it had something to do with Castiel being buddies with Crowley at the time.  That, somehow, them working together could get "a body" (which shouldn't be in Hell anyway) out.

On another note, as mentioned, The Fairies claimed to know of secrets... Which means others could know secrets.  For instance, would Castiel call upon our lil adorable "anti-Christ" to help him... Because that would be cool.  I (like many) are waiting to see what they do with Jesse- or if they will let him just fade away...

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  This post seems to be primarily be opinion based; can you please provide evidence and remove the opinions, this will become a much more acceptable answer!  Good luck on SFF!